# gnuplot of data from an sqlite database of date & time vs temperature?

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi, gnuplot

I have a remote data acquisition system logging site temperatures to an sqlite3 data base on the remote system. The data base contains a 'VIEW' to show the last 48 hours of running data. The remote system periodically exports the results of the data base view to a file called last48.csv which has the following data format:

```
"timestamp", "temp"
"2015-01-15 00:00:02", "18.6"
"2015-01-15 00:15:02", "18.4"
"2015-01-15 00:30:02", "18.2"
"2015-01-15 00:45:02", "18.5"
"2015-01-15 01:00:01", "18.3"
"2015-01-15 01:15:02", "18.2"
```

I'd like to use gnuplot programmaticly to take the last48 file data and generate a graphic file of an x/y line plot of my 48 hours of data (x=datetime vs y=temperature) for inclusion in an html doc that already gets generated and ftped back to my local system.

This is my attempt currently, although I am sure I am at cross purposes in several places (as its mostly a cut and paste / groping in the dark creation):

```
set title '#29 Temperature'
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5   # --- blue
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S"
set ylabel '<Deg C>'
set xrange [2015:2015]
set xlabel '<Time>'
set grid
set term png
set format x "%H/%M"
set output 'TempPlot.png'
plot 'last48.csv' using 1:2
```

I have played around with gnuplot but I am not having much success. I think I am overwhelmed by all the possibilities gnuplot offers.

Assistance and advice would be appreciated. If there is a way to script gnuplot to query the database directly, that would be even better.

Comment: Under which operative system `gnuplot` is running?

Comment: Ii am running gnuplot on linux on a raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

You can execute command calls inside your *gnuplot script*.
(Refer to `help shell` and `help commands` inside *gnuplot*).

So you can ask to your system to generate the output file `last48.csv` from a line similar to

```
! sqlite3 -header -csv my_db.db "select * from my_table;" > last48.csv
```

Of course instead of `select *`, `my_table` etc etc...  you will use the command that you are using to generate by hands your *csv* file.

You may find useful to fix at the running time the current range for the plot (and maybe for the selection rules above). Under Linux you can use the following lines

```
StartDate="\""."`date --date "2 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M`"."\""
EndDate="\""."`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M`"."\"" 
set xrange [StartDate:EndDate]
```

Notes:

- If you have a 'csv' file with more than 48 hour and at the moment of plot generation are e.g. the `16:00` of the `2015-11-12` you can select the **xrange** *sharply* with the following command.

  set xrange ['"2015-01-10 16:00"':'"2015-01-12 16:00"']
- If you run `gnuplot` under Linux you can refer to `man date` to have hints about how to format current date
- Recent versions of `gnuplot` allow to join different strings with the operator `.`. E.g. if A="My ", B="full ", C="string" then D=A.B.C will be "My full string".
- To add a `"` inside a couple of `"..."` you have to protect it with a slash `\` so

  pr "\""

will print a single `"`

Comment: Thanks. I will try out your suggestions.

Comment: gnuplot doesnt seem to like the format of my data file by default. Is there a way to tell it to ignore the quotation marks and delimit columns using the comma instead of whitespace?

Comment: As just suggested [by another good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28013718/3569208) you can add  `set data file separator ','` and `set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. (You cannot simply erase the `"` because in your _x column_ there are some spaces... you could overcome it of course with some complication...). However the `""` should not give you problem after you set the `timefmt`.

Comment: Could be that you must include the quotation marks in the time format: `set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'`. Sorry, cannot test it at the moment, but I remember a question on SO about this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the data file, you must use

```
set datafile separator ','
```

And also use a time format which matches your data:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

The xrange, if set manually must also match the `timefmt`. Or, to make things simple, just use

```
set autoscale xfix
```

to have tightly fit limits.

You can plot directly from sqlite by using the syntax

```
plot '< sqlite ...'
```

were you must direct the output from sqlite to stdout.

Comment: I suppose there's a little missprint (`datafile` should be a single word... at least in gnuplot 4.6)